# Syncing Azure DevOps Repo with GitHub

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, yaml

I am trying to sync my Azure DevOps Repo with my GitHub Organization. I am running in to this error message:

```
fatal: Cannot prompt because terminal prompts have been disabled.
could not read Password for 'https://***@10.16.30.4': terminal prompts disabled
```

Some details that might be helpful (will update as I think of more):

- My Azure DevOps instance is an on-prem server.

I am attempting to follow this guide: https://myownpicloud.wordpress.com/2021/01/20/how-to-synchronize-azure-repos-with-external-git-repos/

Here is my YAML file:

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        mkdir copyrepo

        $sourceurl = "https://ullaha:$(GITHUBPAT)@$(GITHUBREPO)"
        $desturl = "https://$(AZUREPAT)@$(AZUREREPO)"

        Set-Location "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/copyrepo"
        git clone --mirror $sourceURL

        Set-Location "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/copyrepo/DevOpsDefaults.git/"

        Write-Host "*****Git removing remote origin****"
        git remote rm origin
        Write-Output "*****Git remote add****"
        git remote add --mirror=fetch origin $destURL

        Write-Output "*****Git fetch origin****"
        git fetch $sourceURL

        Write-Output "*****Git push to Azure Repos****"
        git push origin --all -f
      errorActionPreference: 'silentlyContinue'
```

Comment: Why do you need to sync two git repositories? What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: my team uses github as the primary repository. We want to implement azure devops for its pipeline functionality (as a start). Since we are operating with an on-prem instance of az devops, it makes it difficult to integrate across to github, I know there is a built in integration in the normal version of az devops, but I dont have the ability to use that. To workaround this, I want to be able to import the repos from github, and periodically check for changes using pipelines.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest creating problems and then trying to solve them. It all seems pretty unnecessary. Why you on-prem Azure DevOps instance can't just use GitHub repo directly?

Comment: Also, why don't you use GitHub Actions for pipelines?

Comment: Unfortunately, while these are good questions, I don't have the answers to them. I've been tasked with using the tools that I have available, which are github, and azure devops

Comment: Some of the tasks should be challenged. Not everything that people ask to be done should be done. For every action, there should be a valid reason. If something doesn't make sense, probably you shouldn't do it. I would first understand the problem and only then would come up with solution.

Comment: So, I rephrase my question. In Azure DevOps you can configure pipeline to use either local Azure DevOps repo or remote repo. Why can't you keep your code in GitHub and configure Azure DevOps pipeline to use it?